# Notification Phonegap with paypal form, is not correct

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, paypal

I'm trying to use a `Phonegap notification` to create a confirmation alert that dsiplays: Are you sure that you want to purchase? yes /no. So if you press a yes, you go to a sandbox Paypal web. If press NO, you are on the same page.

> The problem is that I can't change the action in the form to call the
>   sandbox paypal page.

If I change from the `<form action="htpp:sandobox...">` it is not working properly. It loads a principal paypal page, not the sandbox purchase page.

This is my code, some help?

```
function onConfirm(button){
    alert("button="+button);
    if(button==2){
        return false;
    }else{
        if(button==1){
           document.form.action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"; 
           return true;
        }
    }
}

function openPaypal(){
    navigator.notification.confirm(
               'Pressing Yes will continue to the final part of the order, you will not be able to come back from this point.',      // mensaje (message)
                onConfirm,      // función 'callback' a llamar con el índice del botón pulsado (confirmCallback)
               'Personalised Playing Cards: Are you sure?',            // titulo (title)
               'Yes,Cancel'          // botones (buttonLabels)
                );
}
<form  name="formulario" id="formulario" action="" method="post" onSubmit="return openPaypal()">
    <!-- Indica que vamos a hacer una compra tipo boton comprar ahora -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <!-- Indica que no se presente un campo para notas extras  -->
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <!-- la moneda correspondiente  -->
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input  type="image" src="../images/confirmbutton-passive.png" id="button1" style="width:100%; margin: 0px auto;" border="0" name="submit" alt="Comprar" title="Comprar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you signed in to http://developer.paypal.com during the testing?  If not you could get a page telling you that you need to sign in there before you can use the sandbox.  If you're signed in there in a separate tab, though, you should see the PayPal sandbox login as expected.

Comment: the problem is that if I change this structure, is like the form cant be sended to paypal store...I dont know why...

Answer (score 0):

The principal problem is that if I remove the url from action, I cant load the sandbox paypal page correctly, I can achieved open sandbox paypal but not the page where you can see your purchase with your products, etc...you open a different paypal page, I DONT KNOW WHY!!

And If I dont remove the action url, when you press in "confirm form" the sandbox page is open correctly directly without any permision from the notification.

do u mean?

thanks